# How to not change import or declared constant names but include it in different class

Tags: html, typescript

Earlier i created data .ts class which contained hardcided values for dropdown. But there I had written dropdown values in a constant variable.This constant value is not written in any class.

But now I've used services to fetch data. I've written a fuction in data.ts which retrieves unfo. ,but how am I supposed to give those constant values my fetched data. As i used constant name directly without any class and now with this approach I don't want to change the constant names or any import in corresponding ts or html which have used those dropdown s.

Comment: The code... Where is it

Comment: Earlier
     data.ts 
    Export constant gender=[{id:1,name:'male'}, 
   {id:2,name:'female'}】

In form.ts I assigned values to other dropdown var in onIt functn:
  form.ts
   Import {gender} from 'data.ts'
    Genders=gender;

In html :
     form.html
    <option *ngFor=let gen of genders" >{{gen}}</option>